# react-bootstrap-datetimerangepicker no cancel/clear button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using the datetimerangepicker library for a date selection in a React component. All works fine except for the fact that I only have an 'Apply' button and no option to cancel or clear the selection.

The function to render is:

```
  <DatetimeRangePicker
    autoUpdateInput={false}
    locale={locale}
    isClearable = {true}
    onApply={(event, picker) => this.props.onDateApply(event, picker)}
    onCancel={(event, picker)=>this.props.onDateCancel(event, picker)}
    {...pickerProps}
  >
    <div className="input-group">
      <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.props.eventDate} placeholder="Date or date range"/>
      <Button>
        <img src="calendar.svg" />
      </Button>
    </div>
  </DatetimeRangePicker>
```

As you can see I'm passing in a onDateCancel() prop but this doesn't seem to work. My handler functions (in my parent component) are:

```
  handleDateApply(event, picker) {
    let label = ''
    let start = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') || '';
    let end = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') || '';
    label = start + ' - ' + end;
    if (start === end) {
      label = start;
    }

    this.setState({
      eventStartDate: picker.startDate,
      eventEndDate: picker.endDate,
      eventDate: label
    });

    console.log(picker);
    console.log(this.state.eventStartDate);
    console.log(this.state.eventDate);
  }

  handleDateCancel(event, picker) {
    this.setState({
      eventStartDate: undefined,
      eventEndDate: undefined,
    });
  }
```

And I pass the props through as so:

```
onDateApply={this.handleDateApply}
onDateCancel={this.handleDateCancel}
```

And I bind them to the parent as:

```
this.handleDateApply = this.handleDateApply.bind(this);
this.handleDateCancel = this.handleDateCancel.bind(this);
```

Any help would be gratefully accepted!

Comment: did you solved this ?

Comment: It's quite a while ago so can't be sure but I think I switched to another library:
DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker'

I then added a button manually to clear.